# Renaming the Items in a Tree: Vaadin

Tags: tree, vaadin

I am pretty new to Vaadin, and this might be a simple use case but I am not able to fix this. Any help in this regard would be really helpful.

I have a Vaadin Tree with items added to it. I want to rename the item I click. If you are familiar with the f2 key functionality in windows.

What I want is to click on an item and the item label should give me an option to rename and then I can rename it and on tab out it should get saved.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

As it is discussed [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/511775) it seems editing Trees is not possible without an add-on. You can have a look to [TreeTable](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-treetable) and [ComponentTree](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/componenttree) add-ons whether they can help you.

But I recommend you to implement a `ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener()` to the tree and a TextField. Whenever the item on the tree is clicked you can ask user to type a new ItemName with the help of the textfield and you can update it easily. [Here](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book/#component.tree.itemclicklistener) is an example on ItemClickListener and [here](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book/#component.textfield.databinding) an example for a TextField.

Comment: This is what I have done... I am using Vaadin 7 so the ComponentTree solution is not supported there I believe. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Used a similar approach to anvarik and then marked the tree as dirty to force a repaint. This could be used in conjunction with a pop-up of something similar to create the functionality that you are looking for.

```
// Refresh the tree by marking it as dirty
tree.markAsDirty();
```

For an example look at the OrganizationView within the ThreeSixty application that I am working on that performs this kind of tree updates.

https://github.com/markash/threesixty